# Custom validation doesn't return default error messages

Tags: laravel, laravel-validation

I developed a custom Laravel validation in a package.
In my `provider` I write this code:

```
public function boot()
{
    Validator::resolver(function ($translator, $data, $rules, $messages) {
          return new MyNewValidator($translator, $data, $rules, $messages);
    }); 
}
```

and in `MyNewValidator` class I have this method:

```
public function validateMyValue($attribute, $val, $parameters) {
  .
  .
  .
  if ($blah) {
    return true;
  }else{
    return false;
  }
}
```

after I add my package to `config/app.php` and `composer.json` I trying to use in my request file:

```
public function rules()
{
    return [
        'val' => 'required|my_value'
    ];
}
```

Everything is ok but when validation was failed, Laravel should return the default message like this:

```
The val field is required.
```

but my project return this :

```
validation.my_value
```

Where is my job wrong?

Answer (score 0):

define your custom message

```
`public function message()
{
    return 'my_value is not good.';
}`
```

Comment: Thanks but I want place this message in my package not in request file. How can I place on my package?